# Pricing Debt/Credit/Mortgage+ Prepayment- Literature?

Tags: credit, debt

Does someone know some good literature(Papers or Books) regarding the topic how to Price debt/credit with prepayment?
I just found literature about the general topic , like how to price callable bonds, but I never found literature that clearly states that a debt with a prepayment Option can be f.e. be modelled as a callable bond or a bond with a swaption.
Maybe u have some recommendations?

Thy,

K.S.

Answer (score 0):

Kosta, that would depend on your level of math or background knowledge already on the subject. I believe that a good starting point would be [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Investing-Mortgage-Backed-Asset-Backed-Securities-Financial/dp/1118944003/ref=sr_1_5?ie=UTF8&qid=1484853104&sr=8-5&keywords=mortgage%20backed%20securities). Not heavy on math but it presents the general idea. You can then expand on making the underlying assumptions (default, prepayment arrival) more intricate.